# Webview Oracle Internal Error in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, xcode7, xcode8

When i am loading the webview it is showing as like this in IOS,

2016-11-14 13:02:54.906211 WebViewDemo[325:24769] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
2016-11-14 13:02:54.907976 WebViewDemo[325:24769] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO

can you please help me out[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong on your side. The error is located in the server that hosts the page you are requesting.

Comment: But is opening in safari but not in webview

Comment: You have to provide code if you want help on your coding.

Comment: The page is loading into the webview, you should try to sniff the client-server traffic to see what's going on (this one could help you: https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler)

Answer (score 1):

You may try to switch to [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview) instead of `UIWebView`. `UIWebView` lacks some capabilities, i.e. indexedDB support. If this page works in iOS Safari, chances that it will work with `WKWebView` are relatively high.

Comment: we have tried by using WKWebView but still same thing happens.